# Evaluate the integral $\int_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }(t+6) \delta (-2t+5)dt$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{- \infty }^{+\infty }(t+6)  \delta (-2t+5)dt$$
where $\delta:$ is the Dirac delta function

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is $\delta$ ?

Comment: $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta "function"

Comment: so $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.  Now, please edit to include what you know about the Dirac delta function, and to include what that means here $\delta(-2t+5)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Recall the fundamental property of the [Dirac delta (generalized) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)
$$\int_{- \infty }^{+\infty }f(s) \delta (s)ds=f(0).$$
In your case, change the variable in your integral by letting $s=-2t+5$. Then what is $f(s)$?

Comment: Specifically, we want to use the [translation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation)